# automatically updating WP7 app tile every day from local data

Tags: windows-phone-7, tile

Can you suggest tutorial which describes how to automatically update Windows phone 7 application tile every day? I need to take some local text from binding and put into the tile. 
I have done research on this. Some articles contains information about updating tile from server, some topics contains only parts not full source code or hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a Periodic Task Agent.

Check the last time it was run. If that time was on a different day, then update the tile as needed.

Something like:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    if (task.LastScheduledTime.Date != DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(t => t.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("SOMETHING TO IDENTIFY THE TILE IN QUESTION"));

        if (tile != null)
        {
            var updatedTile = new StandardTileData
            {
                 Title = "WHATEVER",
                 BackContent = "SOME LOCAL DATA"
            };

            tile.Update(updatedTile);
        }
    }

    NotifyComplete();
}
```

For a starter on Background Tasks, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202961(v=VS.92).aspx or for an example on creating one see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Thanks for response! Do I need some reference for Scheduled Task ("Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ScheduledTask' could not be found...") and for NotifyComplete? I am completely newbie

Comment: @Karloss see the links I've added to the answer for more and an example on how to use.

Comment: Trying to understand example on the second link. I compiled it and it seems good enough. May be you know some alternative solution with smaller code amount?